# Save and Read RichText from Access file with Image is SLOW

Tags: vb.net

If I use the following code to write and read rtf data into an access .mdf file its fast to save the data but very slow to read it back.

I tested with a rtf file which is 1mg in size contains around 10 lines in bold and 4 small images.

Is there anyway to read it back faster,

Note if load the rtf from file it takes around 1 sec,

SAVE DATA

```
Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\paul\Documents\Code.mdb"

Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(constring)
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [table1] ([Code]) VALUES (@Code)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", RTB1.Rtf)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    myconnection.Close()
End Using
```

READ DATA

```
Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\paul\Documents\Code.mdb"

Dim ds As New DataSet
Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(constring)
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM table1"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSql, myconnection)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    End Using
    myconnection.Close()
End Using

Me.RTB1.rtf = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
```

Comment: Can't answer your question, but that's an awful lot of data to store in access. If you plan on adding a lot of those you may want to look elsewhere. Access has a 2GB limit.

Comment: ALso..how many records are in there already???? Since you are reading ALL of them.

Comment: for testing purpose one 1 rec in database

Comment: consider storing the RTF file on the filesystem, and just put a path to it into the database. Access is quite slow anyway compared to most DB engines, and it certainly isn't designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: What part of your code is taking the bulk of the the time.  Is it the retrieval from the DB or the assignment of the the RTF to the RichTextbox?  Without testing, I'd wager that it is the assignment of the RTF.

Comment: Well i'm a complete idiot it works fine, there was other code not included here that called another sub (that what was causing the issue) the write and read are actually quite fast, sorry to waste your time.  As said this is probably not best way to store rtf files, since after adding just 1 file with pics the fie size is 10mb, but the actual size of the file as a .rtf is 5mb and as a .doc is 184kb